# Derivation of momentum conservation law for a fluid flowing inside a pipe

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws

Let's consider a fluid which flows inside a pipe with a generic shape. We specifically focus only on a volume $V$ which is delimited by three surfaces: one is the physical Surface of the pipe, while the other two are ideal surfaces which cross the pipe (the sum of these three surfaces generates a close surface). The fluid can flow only through the two ideal surfaces.
By indicating with $\mathbf p$ the momentum, and considering the fluid as a continuos, inside the volume $V$ we have:
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the formula that I ve obtained, I don't know if it is right. My teacher has written (without demonstrating it) the same formula but without the last term with the J Matrix. So someone could say if my demonstration is rigth or not? 
Thanks

Comment: Nobody has an idea?